# Change color series in lineplot

Tags: python, colors, seaborn, line-plot

I am trying to change the default color scheme used by Seaborn on plots, I just want something simple, for instance the HLS scheme shown on their documentation. However their methods don't seem to work, and I can only assume that's due to my use of "hue" but I cannot figure out how to make it work properly. Here's the current code, datain is just a text file of the correct number of columns of numbers, with p as an indexing value:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
datain = np.loadtxt("data.txt")
df = pd.DataFrame(data = datain, columns = ["t","p","x","y","z"])
ax3 = sns.lineplot("t", "x", sns.color_palette("hls"), data = df[df['p'].isin([0,1,2,3,4])], hue = "p")
plt.show()
```

The code plots the first few data sets out of a file, and they come out in that weird purple pastel choice that seaborn seems to default to if I don't include the sns.color_palette function. If I include it I get the error:

```
TypeError: lineplot() got multiple values for keyword argument 'hue'
```

Which seems a bit odd given the format accepted for the lineplot function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: You need to stick to the correct syntax. A palette is supplied via the `palette` argument. Just putting it as the third argument of `lineplot` will let it be interpreted as the third argument of `lineplot` which happens to be `hue`.

Then you will need to make sure the palette has as many colors as you have different `p` values.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datain = np.c_[np.arange(50),
               np.tile(range(5),10),
               np.linspace(0,1)+np.tile(range(5),10)/0.02]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = datain, columns = ["t","p","x"])

ax = sns.lineplot("t", "x", data = df, hue = "p", 
                  palette=sns.color_palette("hls", len(df['p'].unique())))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Woops, I got my arguments very confused, thanks and sorry about that. That helps a lot, thanks! One thing that didn't work for me is `len(df['p'].unique())`, which told me that it was a different length, which is true, my original dataset has 50 unique 'p' tags, and I'm only plotting the first 5 in this sample, easily managed of course. Thanks again!